# How to create a Null shape in shapely

Tags: shapefile, shapely

I want to create a valid Shape object in shapely which has properties but has no geometry.

e.g. For creating features to be saved into a shapefile. All features have attributes/properties but some have null/empty geometry.

I am currently using the workaround of creating an empty GeometryCollection.

```
s = shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection()
s.properties = {"prop1":"val1"}
```

Is there a more suitable/valid approach or a better shapely geometry class for storing null/empty geometry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mix two thinks, Shapely and the [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format.

By definition, Shapely  process  geometric objects and does not deal with attributes

```py
from shapely.geometry import GeometryCollection, mapping
s = GeometryCollection()
# GeoJSON format
geo = mapping(s)
print geo
{'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': []}
```

Now if you want to add attributes, you can use

1) a simple dictionary

```py
feature = {}
feature['geometry'] = GeometryCollection()
feature['properties'] = {"prop1":"val1"}
print feature
{'geometry': <shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection object at 0x107b594d0>, 'properties': {'prop1': 'val1'}}
```

2) the [geo_interface](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) (GeoJSON like) protocol used by Shapely, [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html), among others (see [Python Geo_interface applications](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications)))

```py
geojson = {"type":"feature","geometry":geo,  "properties":  {"prop1":"val1"}}
print geojson
{'geometry': {'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': []}, 'type': 'feature', 'properties': {'prop1': 'val1'}}
```

And you don't need shapely for that, simply use Python dictionaries

```py
geo = {'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': []}
geojson = {"type":"feature","geometry":geo,  "properties":  {"prop1":"val1"}}
```

3) If you have many features

```py
geojsons = [{"type":"feature","geometry":geo,  "properties":  {"prop1":"val1"}},{"type":"feature","geometry":geo,  "properties":  {"prop1":"val2"}},{"type":"feature","geometry":geo,  "properties":  {"prop1":"val3"}},{"type":"feature","geometry":geo,  "properties":  {"prop1":"val4"}}]
result = {"type": "FeatureCollection",  "features":geojsons,}
print result
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': []}, 'type': 'feature', 'properties': {'prop1': 'val1'}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': []}, 'type': 'feature', 'properties': {'prop1': 'val2'}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': []}, 'type': 'feature', 'properties': {'prop1': 'val3'}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': []}, 'type': 'feature', 'properties': {'prop1': 'val4'}}]}
```

But a shapefile without geometry  makes no sense, why not use a simple database or a [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) GeoDataFrame ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
df = pd.DataFrame({'prop1' : ['Val1','Val2','Val3']})
geometry = [GeometryCollection(),GeometryCollection(),GeometryCollection()]
# convert the DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,geometry=geometry)
print geo_df
   prop1  geometry
0  Val1   ()
1  Val2   ()
2  Val3   ()
```

If you want to add real geometries after, simply change the values of the 'geometry' tag in geojsons or the 'geometry' column in the GeoDataFrame and
you can save the resulting shapefile with [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html) or directly with GeoPandas

```py
 geo_df['geometry'] = geo_df['geometry'].apply(lambda x : Point(1,2))
 print geo_df
   prop1     geometry
 0  Val1  POINT (1 2)
 1  Val2  POINT (1 2)
 2  Val3  POINT (1 2)
```

Save the resulting shapefile

```py
geo_df.to_file('out.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: Many thanks @gene this was useful to help untangle/understand the different tools. I am still interested to know if there is a way to create a valid shapely shape with Null geometry. I believe this might help interoperability with PostGIS/MySQL, which allow multiple records in the same table, where some have actual geometry and others are simply Null. e.g. Perhaps something like ```s = shapely.geometry.collection.BaseGeometry()```? Or perhaps an empty GeometryCollection already allows this?

Comment: The purpose of Shapely is not to work with empty geometries ( valid shapely shape with Null geometry) and tables (multiple records). For that you can simply  use  GeoJSON. You can eventually create an empty GeometryCollection (`GeometryCollection()` and fill it after

Answer (score 5):

Creating an empty geometry collection is the recommended way to get a null geometry.

From [The Shapely User Manual](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#empty-features):

> An “empty” feature is one with a point set that coincides with the
>   empty set; not `None`, but like `set([])`. Empty features can be created
>   by calling the various constructors with no arguments. Almost no
>   operations are supported by empty features.

Hence, what you have been doing is the standard way to create a Null geometry in Shapely. You can make it a little bit shorter:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point # or Polygon, LineString, etc. It doesn't matter.
empty = Point()
print empty # prints "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY"
```